# Time spent multiplying with expoDC and D&C

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

Let

$T(m,n) \leq that$

1. $0$ if n = 1
2. $T(m,n/2) + M(mn/2,mn/2)$ if n is even
3. $T(m, n-1) + M(m, (n-1)m)$ otherwise

The time to do $a^n$ where m is the size of a (the number of figures).

If $M(q,s) \in \Theta(sq^{\alpha -1})$ for some constant $\alpha$ when $s \geq q$ prove that

$T(m,n) \in O(m^\alpha n^\alpha)$

Any advice?

Comment: In what context did you encounter this problem? What are your thoughts on how to approach it?

Comment: The problem is from chapter 7 of Fundamentals of Algorithmics from Brassard. I tried to add the n-1 multiplications but I n^{\alpha + 1}m^{\alpha}.